# Android Studio with No Proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy

My System has **No Proxy Server**

[image]

So I updated my proxy settings as **No Proxy**

[image]

Also I have commented out proxy settings in my `gradle.properties`

```
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Still I'm getting

> Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind
>   an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or
>   Gradle.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Having same problem for no reason

Answer (score 2):

For any future people with issues like that.

TL;DR

0. remove proxy settings from android studio.
1. remove proxy settings from your android project gradle.properties file
2. remove proxy settings from your PC/MAC gradle system files, located at your USER/your OS working directory/gradle/gradle.properties file.

What happened?

Because of *insert_reason* you turn on proxy(global proxy for all connections) for android studio, gradle took those proxy settings and installed them as default connection so removing proxy from android studio or reinstalling is not enough, gradle.properties will force proxy settings from gradle.properties outside of your android studio.